# RAID Not Working

Tags: raid

I'm trying to make my 5 HDD's into a RAID. So far I've done the command below

```
sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=linear --raid-devices=5 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf
```

From reading the web, they say you have to put a file system on it and mount it. I can't seem to do either. When I try and mount the drive it gives the problem below.

```
sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt/raiddrives

wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0,
missing codepage or helper program, or other errror
```

When I try put a file system on the drives it gives me another error.

```
mkfs.xfs /dev/md0
bash: mkfs.xfs: command not found
```

Is there a not a default file system creator program installed with Linux by default? All the guides seem to use mkfs but Ubuntu 14 doesn't seem to have it installed.  And even after I do the command below I still get the same bash error as above.

```
sudo apt-get install xfsprogs
```

Answer (score 0):

Default in ubuntu would be ext4 so your command:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0
```

But you should follow all the steps from http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Software-RAID and check if the raid was created correctly with:

```
sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
```